# Nested aggregation subgrouping results with Mongodb aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mongoose-populate

I have a dataset with metrics collected from a group of sensors.
My dataset looks like this:

```
{type: 1, display: 'foo', value: 'A'}
{type: 2, display: 'bar', value: 'B'}
{type: 2, display: 'foo', value: 'B'}
```

I am trying to aggregate the results and get some meaning insights via a REST API. I am somehow trying to produce aggregated results as:

```
[{
  type: 1, 
  displays: [
    {
      name: 'foo',
      count: 1
    }
  ],
  values: [
    {
      name: 'A',
      count: 1
    }
  ],
  total_count: 1
},{
  type: 2, 
  displays: [
    {
      name: 'foo',
      count: 1
    } , {
      name: 'bar',
      count: 1
    }
  ],
  values: [
    {
      name: 'B',
      count: 2
    }
  ],
  total_count: 2
}]
```

Summarizing the aggregated results and producing shallow results is straight forward, I am struggling though as I can't created the nested counters for `types` and `displays` all together. 
I have tried to use various aggregation operators with no luck. 
Basically I can get one group by types or displays as:

```
db.logs.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          type: '$type',
          display: '$display'
        },
        count: { $sum: 1 }
      }
    }, {
      $group: {
      _id: '$_id.type',
      displays: {
        $push: {
          name: "$_id.display",
          count: "$count"
        }
      }
      }
    }
  ]);
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you add the aggregation pipeline you have to the post ?

Comment: @Veeram I have added a sample pipeline that works for displays, I am not quite sure how can I summarize nested multiple fields or how can I aggregate total counts.

Comment: do you want to summarize **all** fields ? Your expected output is not a valid json. You have `display` key twice in a document.

Comment: I think it can help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52175655/group-count-2-item-object-array-mongodb/52249547#52249547

Comment: @NetoSilva Do you suggest using lookups within the same collection? The data for the subgroups is still inside the parsed documents tho.